# How do we measure mass distribution in an object?

Tags: mass, density

Given an object I want to know the mass distribution among different section.
What are the inexpensive methods to know this ?

Comment: How much is your time worth? If it's worth a lot, I would go with a CT. If it's worth next to nothing, you can balance a rigid object around multiple axes and measure the moments exerted on it by gravity. The rest is "a bit" of math to solve the inverse problem to get the mass distribution from the moments. I would probably go with the CT, though.

Comment: @CuriousOne What is CT ?

Comment: Computer tomography (digital x-ray). Not sure how much you would have to pay for an industrial scan, but it's probably less than the time and effort is worth that you would have to invest in other ways of reconstructing a mass (i.e. density) distribution to a similar precision (at least without cutting up the object). If the CT doesn't work because the object is too large, heavy, dense or can't stand radiation, it may get tough from there. At least I am not aware of an industrial solution other than imaging that is available off the shelf. I may be wrong about that.